# Trouble deleting params from Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stumped by this.  I have a string which includes all the to_s equivalents of their respective params. I deleted one from the string `current_user.privilege.factory`, but the attribute still goes through just fine. Please help.

```
  def all_params
    [ticket_attrs, required_attrs, production_attrs, internal_attrs,
     progress_attrs].flatten
  end

  def ticket_params
    if current_user.general_privilege == 'part-admin'
      params.require(:ticket).permit authorized_params
    else
      params.require(:ticket).permit all_params
    end
  end

  def authorized_params
    factory = params[:ticket][:manufacturing_location]

    filtered_params = all_params
    filtered_params.each do |param|
      unless current_user.privilege.send(factory).include?(param.to_s)
        filtered_params.delete param 
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.

```
all_params.map! do |key| 
  key if current_user.privilege.send(factory).include?(key.to_s)
end
```